# How to convert class properties of single type to list of that type

Tags: c#, linq, types, reflection, casting

Given the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    readonly MyType Object1 = new MyType { Prop1="Prop I want", Prop2="Prop I dont want"}
    readonly MyType Object2 = new MyType { Prop1="Prop I want", Prop2="Prop I dont want"}
    readonly MyType Object3 = new MyType { Prop1="Prop I want", Prop2="Prop I dont want"}
    readonly MyType Object4 = new MyType { Prop1="Prop I want", Prop2="Prop I dont want"}
    // etc, there are 100+ in this class, all of the type MyType
}
```

Is there a way I can turn this into a list of either the type `MyType` or the prop `Prop1`?

The class only contains properties of the type `MyType`.

Comment: Do you mean automatically?

Comment: If by automatically you mean by writing code to convert it, yes. I dont want to make the list manually as there are way too many objects, with more to come later probably.

Comment: @JonasMohammed you need to use Reflection. Just search about it, you'll find tons of answers.

Comment: Are all your members `private readonly`?

Comment: Do you mean too many objects, or too many properties in the class, or too many classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, we will use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to get a list of all strings in the `Prop1` properties of all fields in `MyClass`.

Given that you have some instance of `MyClass`, you can get the list of strings with a simple one-liner like this:

```cs
MyClass instance = new MyClass(); // This could of course be gotten from somewhere else.

List<string> prop1s = instance.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().Select(p => (MyType)p.GetValue(instance)).Select(p => p.Prop1).ToList();
```

If you suddenly want to get some other property inside of `MyType`, you can simply change which property you select in the last `Select()`.

Here we use reflection to get all fields (`.GetRunTimeFields()`) inside of the type `MyClass`, and since we know that all fields are of type `MyType` we can just cast all of the fields to `MyType` and then simply select the `Prop1` property. Finally we just do `ToList()` to have it as a list, you could of course use it as an `IEnumerable<string>` or an array, but hopefully this should show you how you get the property you wanted as as list.

If you instead just want to have a list of `MyType`, then you could skip the last `Select()` like this:

```cs
List<MyType> myTypes = instance.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().Select(p => (MyType)p.GetValue(instance)).ToList();
```